# Where do you get the key for Breezehome?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where do you get the key to the Breezehome? I can't find it.

Comment: Hi, usually, we use the body section to add some details about the question, not just repeating the title. Where have you searched or what have you tried to solve the problem yourself could be good adds to your question.

Comment: Perhaps your title could have some more useful information? Like what stage in the game you're in or what platform you're on. Anything helps.

Answer (score 10):

Breezehome can be purchased from [Proventus Avenicci](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Proventus_Avenicci) (Jarl Balgruuf's steward) after becoming Thane of Whiterun by slaying your first dragon.